# storage must be a werkzeug.FileStorage(FLASK-UPLOAD)

Tags: exception, flask-uploads

Hello Everyone,

This is my first time here. I have been having issues regarding the flask_upload to upload the files. I am not sure where I am going wrong with the flask_upload. Hence every time I have been trying to upload the file it is throwing the error in the title

```
(** storage must be a werkzeug.FileStorage)
```

enter image description here**)

I am attaching the pictures of my application factory, along with the config file and the html file.Any help will be greatly appreciated.Since I am not sure where I am going wrong

```
        
            {% block content %}
                <h1>upload files</h1>
                <form action="{{ url_for('rep.upload') }}" method="post",enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                    <p>
                        {{ form.report_title.label }}<br>
                        {{ form.report_title(size=32) }}<br>
                        {% for error in form.report_title.errors %}
                        <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        {{ form.report_description.label }}<br>
                        {{ form.report_description(size=64) }}<br>
                        {% for error in form.report_description.errors %}
                        <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                        {% endfor %}
        
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        {{ form.report_file.name }}<br>
                        {{ form.report_file}}<br>
                        {% for error in form.report_file.errors %}
                        <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                        {% endfor %}
        
                    </p>
                    <p>{{ form.submit() }}</p>
        
                    </form>
            {% endblock %}
        
        




        enter code here



(Report Blueprint)
        @rep.route("/add",methods=['GET','POST'])
        @login_required
        @roles_requried("patient")
        def upload():
            form = AddReportForm()

            if form.validate_on_submit():
                print(request.files.get('report_file'))
                filename = images.save(request.files.get('report_file'),name="Hello",folder="static/img",)
                url = images.url(filename)
                data = {"report_title":form.report_title.data,"report_description":form.report_description.data,
                            "report_filename":filename,"report_url":url}
                print(data)
                new_report = Report(**data)
                new_report.save()
                flash( 'New report, {}, added!'.format(new_report.report_title), 'success')
                return redirect(url_for('user.profile'))
            return render_template(template_name_or_list='user/add_report.html',form=form)

    enter code here
        [config.py]

            UPLOADS_DEFAULT_DEST = '/static/img/'
            UPLOADS_DEFAULT_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/img/'

            UPLOADED_IMAGES_DEST =  '/static/img/'
            UPLOADED_IMAGES_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/img/'

    enter code here
    (extensions)
    images = UploadSet('images',IMAGES)

        enter code here

        (Application Factory)
        app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
            app.config.from_object(config_settings)
            handler = RotatingFileHandler(app.config.get('LOGGING_LOCATION'), maxBytes=10240,backupCount=10 )
            handler.setLevel(app.config.get('LOGGING_LEVEL'))
            formatter = handler.setFormatter(app.config.get('LOGGING_FORMAT'))
            handler.setFormatter(formatter)

            patch_request_class(app, 32 * 1024 * 1024 )


            app.register_blueprint(user)
            app.register_blueprint(doc)
            app.register_blueprint(adm)
            app.register_blueprint(rep)
            configure_uploads(app, images)


            app.logger.addHandler(handler)

            error(app)
            extensions(app)
```